# Can not getting Marker on Current Location

Tags: android, google-maps

I am working on google map.

My code is as follows :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements LocationListener {

private GoogleMap map;
private LocationManager mLocationManager;
private Location mLocation;
boolean isGPSEnabled;
boolean isNetworkEnabled;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Inside OnCreate", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    initializeMap();
}


@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

}


// To Initialize Map..
protected void initializeMap() {

    if (map == null) {
        map = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(
                R.id.map)).getMap();
        if (map == null) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Sorry! Map Is Not Created",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        ////Function calling here...
        getCurrentLocaion();
    }

    //For Zoomin, ZoomOut
    map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    // Adding and showing marker while touching the GoogleMap
    map.setOnMapClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onMapClick(LatLng arg0) {
            // Clears any existing markers from the GoogleMap
            map.clear();

            // Creating an instance of MarkerOptions to set position
            MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();

            // Setting position on the MarkerOptions
            markerOptions.position(arg0);

            // Animating to the currently touched position
            map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(arg0));

            // Adding marker on the GoogleMap
            Marker marker = map.addMarker(markerOptions);

            // Showing InfoWindow on the GoogleMap
            marker.showInfoWindow();

        }
    });
}

public void getCurrentLocaion() {
    // Getting Current Location..
    mLocationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
    boolean isGPSEnabled = mLocationManager
            .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    // getting network status
    boolean isNetworkEnabled = mLocationManager
            .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
    if (!isGPSEnabled && !isNetworkEnabled) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "GPS is not Enabled", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } else {
        // First get location from Network Provider
        if (isNetworkEnabled) {
            mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                    LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,
                    5000,
                    5000, MainActivity.this);

            if (mLocationManager != null) {
                mLocation = mLocationManager
                        .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                if (mLocation != null) {
                    onLocationChanged(mLocation);
                }
            }
        }
        // if GPS Enabled get lat/long using GPS Services
        if (isGPSEnabled) {
            if (mLocation == null) {
                if (checkSelfPermission(android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && checkSelfPermission(android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    // TODO: Consider calling
                    //    public void requestPermissions(@NonNull String[] permissions, int requestCode)
                    // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
                    //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
                    //                                          int[] grantResults)
                    // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
                    // for Activity#requestPermissions for more details.
                    return;
                }
                mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                        LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                        5000,
                        5000, this);
                if (mLocationManager != null) {
                    mLocation = mLocationManager
                            .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                    if (mLocation != null) {

                        //Called here...
                        onLocationChanged(mLocation);

                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}



////Called in getCurrentLocation function...
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    map.clear();
    MarkerOptions mp = new MarkerOptions();
    mp.title("My Postion");
    mp.position(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()));

    map.addMarker(mp);
    map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(
            new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()), 13));
    //TO ADD ZOOMIN-ZOOMOUT button...
    map.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
}
```

The Problem is that Marker is not displaying on current Position when I launch application, its working when I click on map.

What should be the problem ?

Comment: add `@Override` before `onLocationChanged(....)`

Comment: removed but still not getting...

Comment: added but not displaying

Comment: Not sure what the solution is, but use logging or a debugger to find where it goes wrong.  Is onLocationChanged even being called?

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
    private GoogleMap mMap;

   mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(BNE_LOCATION)
            .title("Washington Park")
            .snippet("425, New Jersey")
            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
            .fromResource(R.drawable.pin_red)));
```

Comment: I have added your above code in my onCreate() method by passing static values for LatLong but, still marker is not displayed.